# Command Prompt cannot find file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, directory

I am trying to write a path in Command Prompt and adding deleting command to it but when it comes to execute it, it tells me that "The system cannot find the file specified", however I have them all listed and checked.

The code I am using is:

```
forfiles -p "H:\TestingFolder2" -s /D -<1> /C "cmd /c echo "Y" | del @path"
```

Comment: `/D -<1>`? you surely want to use `/D -1`?

Comment: @Stephan yeah, why not?

Comment: and? does it work?

Comment: As it was mentioned in the heading of the topic, the "Command Prompt cannot find file", so I can't say until this issue will be solved

Comment: as long as you have any redirection in your command line, (`<1>`), it won't get solved. Replace `/D -<1>` with  `/D -1` and check.

Comment: Ok, thank you, didn't knew that this would affect so much!

Comment: you may want to delete your question due it was caused by a typing error / syntax error.

Comment: @Damo `<` and `>` have special meaning (it are [redirection operators](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)). So adding them will have a pretty great affect. Advice to you: don't add extra characters if they are not needed ;-)

Comment: Besides the `<`/`>` issue, you have nested quotation marks after the `/C` part, so you need to escape the inner ones by `\"` or `0x22`, so you have `... echo \"Y\" ...` or `... echo 0x22Y0x22 ...`. Anyway, why do you echo a `Y` into the `del` command? `del` does not prompt for `Y`/`N` here as `@path` is expanded to a dedicated path; `del` prompts only in case global wildcards (`*`, `?`) are used; so remove everything from `echo` to the pipe symbol `|`...

Comment: @Stephan, you could close-vote or flag the question accordingly...

Comment: @aschipfl just in case, I am a very new in it. by the way, the issue is that when I use the code, it does erase my files, which is good, but it keeps folders that are inside, but they are just empty, so I wonder what should I change to make folder to be deleted as well. and the other issue is that I have restricted folders and files (separated), and i want to keep them, however, when code is executed, those restricted folders are ok, they are not touched, the restricted files however (they are separate, not in restricted folders) are deleted as if they are just common ones.

Comment: @ J.Baoby yeah I know, I just don't know if in this case they were or were not required, before issue was solved :)

Comment: Why didn't you include all this in your question initially? The [`del` command](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) deletes *files*, while the [`rd` command](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) removes *directories*. Ah, and if you want a user to be notified by your comment, do *not* put a _space_ after the `@` symbol...

Comment: Well because I didn't knew about it before the first issue was solved.